# When is an Integer a Rational Number, and are All Ratios Rational, Even $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, real-numbers, rational-numbers

> $$\Bbb{Q} = \left\{\frac ab \mid \text{$a$ and $b$ are integers and $b \ne 0$} \right\}$$
>
> *In other words, **a rational number is a number that can be written as one integer over another.***
>
> For an integer, the denominator is $1$ in that case. For example, $5$ can be written as $\dfrac 51$.

Is $5$ a rational number? Or is $\dfrac 51$  a rational number? I'm not able to figure out what the definition is actually saying. What are the numbers that cannot be written as one integer over another?

> Irrational numbers are the numbers that cannot be written as one integer over another. Roots of numbers that are not perfect squares are examples of irrational numbers.

However, what is this then: $\dfrac {\sqrt 7} {2}$?

Comment: Every integer is a rational number, as you showed, yet $\,\frac{\sqrt 7}2\,$ is **not** a rational since it is not a quotient of two integers...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$ is not rational, because $\sqrt{7}$ is not an integer. Have you seen a proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, e.g., where you suppose $\sqrt{2} = p/q$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime integers, and get a contradiction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any number for which *it is possible* to express as the ratio or quotient of **integers** is a *rational number. So yes,* $5$ is rational, because it *is possible* to express this as $\frac 51, \frac {10}{2}...$.

$5$ is also an integer. Every integer is a rational number, but not all rational numbers, e.g. $\frac 12$, is an integer. We know $\frac 12$ is rational, because it is the quotient of two integers.

However, $\dfrac {\sqrt 7}{2}$ is **not** a ratio of **integers**. It is a ratio of a non-integer, namely $\sqrt 7$, over an integer. So $\dfrac{\sqrt 7}{2}$ is not rational.

Comment: $0.5$ is a rational number because it can be expressed as a quotient of two integers, i.e. $\frac 12$. But what about     $\frac {0.5}{1}$ ? The numerator in this case is not a integer. Nevertheless, the answer is '$\frac {0.5}{1}=0.5$' which is a rational number.

Comment: $\frac{0.5}{1} = 0.5 = \frac 12$. Since *it is possible* to equate $0.5$ as a ratio of integers, it is rational, whatever form it takes. We don't necessarily have to *use* any given form, we only need to know it is *possible* to equate it with a quotient/ratio of integers.

Comment: @amWhy: This might be on its way to a nice answer badge :-) +1

Comment: It's not that obvious that $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$ is irrational. One could use a similar argument to "prove" that $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{7}}$ is irrational.

Comment: @Pedro, I carefully stated that *if it is possible to express a number as the ratio of two integers,* then it is rational. $\sqrt 7/\sqrt 7 = \sqrt{7/7} = \sqrt 1 = 1 = \frac 11$. Hence, since it is possible to express as a ratio of integers, it is rational. $\sqrt{7}/2$ cannot be expressed as the ratio of two integers. The OP understands (see post) that unless an integer is a perfect square, it's sqrt is irrational.

Comment: Your statement "So yes, 5 is rational,..." may or may not *actually* since as Marty Cohen explains in his answer one construction of the rational numbers is as a set of  equivalence class of ordered pairs of integers. Using this definition, the rationals and the integers are actually disjoint. However, one might be able construct the rationals and the integers in such a way that the integers are a subset of the rational. Moreover, even if the integers and rational are disjoint, their is a canonical inclusion of the integers into the rationals.

Comment: @amWhy however you are not proving that $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$ since you must prove first (as Pedro said) that every square root of a natural that is not perfect square is irrational. And the OP seems not so aware of the fact unless he mentions it on post, and I suppose he hasn't proven that. That is done later. Things are not so easy. I think your response is not the right one unless the OP marked it.

Comment: $\sqrt7$ is a solution to $x^2-7=0$. It can not be rational due to the Rational Root Theorem. See  Arnold, D.; Arnold, G. (1993). Four unit mathematics. Edward Arnold. pp. 120–121.

Comment: Also see this answer by fleablood for proof of the Rational Root Theorem. 

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3558611/928654

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{7}$ is not a rational number.

You can prove it by the absurd.

Suppose that you can write it as $\sqrt{7}=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ natural numbers.

You can suppose without loss of generality that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.
 Decompose $a$ and $b$ in prime factors: $a=a_1^{n_1}\dots a_k^{n_k}$ and $b=b_1^{m_1}\dots b_l^{m_l}$. All the $a_i$ are primes and different of all the $b_j$ (also primes) because $a$ $b$ are coprime.

$\sqrt{7}=\frac{a}{b}$ give you $7=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ hence $a^2=7\cdot b^2$ hence $a_1^{2n_1}\dots a_k^{2n_k}=7b_1^{2m_1}\dots b_l^{2m_l}$ hence one of the $a_i$ is $7$ (lets say $a_1=7$). We have: $7^{2n_1-1}\dots a_k^{2n_k}=b_1^{2m_1}\dots b_l^{2m_l}$ hence $7$ divide $b_1^{2m_1}\dots b_l^{2m_l}$ hence one of the $b_j$ is $7$ contradiction with $a$ $b$ coprimes.

Comment: Why are you allowed to assume they are coprime?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes If they are not you can write $a=a'.k$ and $b=b'.k$ for some integer $k$ and with $a'$ and $b'$ coprime. Hence $\sqrt{7}=a/b=a'.k/(b'.k)=a'/b'$.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are many answers here already, unless if I have missed something none of them actually proves that $\sqrt{7}/2$ is irrational.  As already noted in the comments to amWhy's answer, it is not valid to say that if $a$ is not an integer then $a/b$ is irrational.  However, it is valid to say that if $a$ is irrational and $b$ is rational, then $a/b$ is irrational.  (This is because if $a/b$ and $b$ were both rational, then their product $a$ would be rational because the product of rational numbers is always rational.)  Because $\sqrt{7}$ is irrational (as shown in wece's answer) and 2 is rational, the ratio $\sqrt{7}/2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2):

As $5$ can be written as $\frac 51$, yes, $5$ is a **rational number**. All integers are also rational. The **fraction** $\frac{\sqrt 7}2$ does not denote a rational number because the numerator $\sqrt 7$ is not an integer.

Comment: Your argument for saying that $\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$ is not a rational number lays out false. For example: $r=\frac{4}{123}$ and $s=\frac{r}{21}$, then for you $s$ is not rational, since $r$ is not integer.

Answer (score 1):

$5$ is an integer and a rational number. It is convention that we omit the denominator when it is $1$.

$\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$ is not a rational number as it does not conform to the definition i.e., the numerator is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

A and B have to be integers. Square root 7 is not an integer. It is irrational so it does not qualify as being a rational number. Yes 5/1 is rational. It perfectly satisfies the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Rational numbers are usually defined in terms of the integers.

I would define a rational number
as an ordered pair of integers
$(a, b)$ such that $b \ne 0$.
I would then define equality for rational numbers
by $(a, b) = (c, d)$ if and only if
$ad = bc$.

With the interpretation of $(a, b)$
as the rational number $a/b$,
this means that $a/b = c/d$
if and only if $ad = bc$.
In other words,
our previous knowledge of how
rational number should behave
drives all our definitions relating to 
these rational numbers.

For example, since we want
$a/b + c/d = (ad+bd)/bd$,
we would $define$ addition by
$(a, b)+(c,d) = (ad+bc, bd)$.
We would then show that
these "rational numbers"
behave exactly like we want rational numbers to behave.

Finally, we would say
"From now on, we will write
$(a, b)$ as $a/b$",
and then forget all the constructions
since we have laboriously constructed
something we we already quite familiar with.

Another example of this is defining all integers
in terms of positive integers.
We can write an integer as
an ordered pair of positive integers
$(a, b)$
with equality being defined by
$(a, b) = (c, d)$ if and only if
$a+d = b+c$.
This is because we want $(a, b)$ to mean $a-b$,
and $a-b = c-d$ is the same as
$a+d = b+c$.
This reason we use this definition of equality
is that, in our definition
of "integers", we can only use positive integers,
where addition is always possible, but subtraction is not always possible.

Similarly, in our definition of
rational numbers in terms of integers,
multiplication is always possible,
but division is not always possible.

For more than you probably want to know
about this process,
read "Foundations of Analysis" by Edmund Landau.
This starts with constructing the integers
and ends up with the complex numbers.