# Explanation of the rational root theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I just discovered the rational root theorem and I feel like I can understand it if I can get past the notational jargon presented in Wikipedia.

Here's what I think I understood. If $r$ is a rational solution of a polynomial $f(x)$ then the function can be rewritten as $(x-r)(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is another polynomial. Expanding thus with $r$ places it in the constant term. Assuming for $g(x) \implies a, f(x) \implies -ar \quad \text{As the constant}$. So r is divisible by the constant term.

First of all, is that correct. And is there a way to explain the proof for the theorem without scary notation?

Comment: What does it mean to say that $r$ is "in the constant term"?  Consider the polynomial $4x^2-4x+1$.  That has a (rational) root at $x=\frac 12$.  Is that "in the constant term"?

Comment: It's sort of divisible by the constant term. But you see that doesn't make sense to me, how you got that number.

Comment: Well, I got it by starting with $\left( x-\frac 12\right)^2$ and then clearing the denominator.

Comment: But you could use the rational root theorem to narrow down the list of suspects.  The theorem tells us that, in this case, "if $\frac mn$ is a root (assuming the fraction is in lowest terms) then $m\,|\,1$ and $n\,|\,4$.  Thus the only candidates would be $\pm 1, \pm \frac 12,\pm \frac 14$" so you could find it that way.

Comment: As another example. consider $(x-2)(x-3)=x^2-5x+6$.  Clearly, that has roots at $2$ and $3$.  Neither of those are divisible by the constant term $6$.

Comment: If the leading coefficient is $1$, a rational root must be even an integer root and divide the constant term (The root is a divisor of the constant term , it is not divisble in general by the constant term).

Comment: Or did I mean that 6 is divisible by either one of the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *statement* of the rational root theorem is that if polynomial with integer coeficients is $P(x) =a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ...... + a_1x + a_0$ has a rational root (bear in mind it may have irrational roots) the ration root, call it $r$, will but be of the form $r = \frac jk$ where $j$ is a factor of $a_0$ and $k$ is a factor of $a_n$.

For instance if  $2x^2 -9x + 4$ has any rational roots (it might not) then, as factors of $4$ are $\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm 4$ and the factors of $2$ are $\pm 1, \pm 2$, then the rational roots will be of the form $\frac jk$ where $j = \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm4$ and $k = \pm 1, \pm 2$ and, indeed, $r_1 = 4=\frac 41$ is one root, and $r_2 = \frac 12 =\frac 12$ is another.

And the *proof* can go like this:

Let $P(x) = a_nx^n + ..... + a_0$.  Now for any $b$ we can do synthetic division to divide $P(x)$ but $x-b$ to get some $\frac {P(x)}{x-b} = c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + c_{n-2}x^{n-2}+ .... + c_1x + c_0 + \frac s{x-b}$ and if we write $c_{n-1}x^{n-2} + c_{n-2}x^{n-2}+ .... + c_1x + c_0$ as $Q(x)$ we get $P(x) = (x-b)Q(x) + s$ where $s$ is a remainder constant.

Now if it turns out that $b$ was one of the roots of $P(x)$ we would have $P(b) = (b-b)Q(b) + s= s$.  That means $s= 0$ and $P(x) = (x-b)Q(x)$.

ANd that means that $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ..... + a_1x + a_0$ and $P(x) = (x- b)Q(x) = (x-b)(c_{n-1}x^{n-1} + c_{n-2}x^{n-2}+ .... + c_1x + c_0) = c_{n-1}x^n + (c_{n-2}-bc_{n-1})x^{n-1} + ....... +(c_0 -bc_1)x + c_0b$.

And that means  $c_0b = a_0$ and so $b=\frac {a_0}{c_0}$.  If $b$ is rational then $\frac {a_0}{c_0}$ when reduced to lowest terms will have a factor of $a_0$ in the numerator.

The also means $c_{n-1} = a_n$ and $c_{n-2}-bc_{n-1} = c_{n-2}-ba_n = a_{n-1}$.

This means $b = \frac {c_{n-2}-a_{n-1}}{a_n}$. And if $b$ is rational then $ \frac {c_{n-2}-a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ when reduced to lowest terms will have a factor of $a_n$ in the  denominator.

......

I've never done this before but let's see if we do an example:

Take $P(x) = 2x^2 -9x + 4$ and divide it by $x-\frac 12$.

We get $P(x) = 2x^2 - 9x + 4 = 2x(x-\frac 12) + x -9x +4 =$

$2x(x-\frac 12) - 8x + 4 = 2x(x-\frac 12) - 8(x-\frac 12) +(-4) + 4=$

$2x(x-\frac 12) - 8(x-\frac 12) = (x-\frac 12)(2x -8)$.

Now if we expand that out we will have $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ where:

$A = 2*1=2$ and $B=-8-\frac 12*2= -8-r*A$ and $C=-\frac 12*(-8)=-r*(-8)$.

So $\frac 12=r =\frac {-8-B}{A}$.  so we must have the denominator of $r$ divide $A$.  And, indeed, the denominator of $r$ is $2$ and $A$ is $2$.

And $\frac 12=r=\frac {-C}{-8}$ so we must have the numerator of $r$ divide $C$.  And indeed, then numerator of $r$ is $1$ and $C= 4$.

Comment: Took a lot of words but I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Take your polynomial $p(x) = a_0  + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \dotsb + a_n x^n  = 0$. We can take the $a_i$ as having no common factor, as we could divide it out. If $u/v$ is a rational zero of $p(x)$, written in lowest terms, substitute and multiply by $v^n$:

$\begin{align*}
  a_0
        + a_1 \frac{u}{v}
        + a_2 \frac{u^2}{v^2}
        + \dotsb
        + a_n \frac{u^n}{v^n}
         &= 0 \\
a_0 v^n
        + a_1 u v^{n - 1}
        + a_2 u^2 v^{n - 2}
        + \dotsb
        + a_n u^n
         &= 0 
\end{align*}$

All terms are integers. The second to the last terms are all divisible by $u$, so the first one must be divisible by $u$ also, thus $a_0$ is divisible by $u$. In the same way, considering the first up to the next to last terms and $v$, $a_n$ is divisible by $v$.